# Blazor rerenders page again

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, server-side-rendering, blazor-webassembly

This is my code:

```
@page "/Car/Details/{carId}"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@inherits CarBase
@using BlazorApp.Components.Pages.Cars.Services
@inject IJSRuntime JS

@code {

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (Car == null)
        {
            await GetCarDetails();
        }

    }

}
<PageTitle>Car</PageTitle>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
            @if (Car!= null)
            {
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h4>@Car.Name</h4>
                    <h6>@Car.Name is @Car.Status</h6>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" @disabled="@Car.IsSold">Mark Sold</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" @disabled="@Car.IsRented">Rent Car</button>
                </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p>Loading...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Car gets the values when the GetCarDetails method is called from CarBase and everything gets displayed as it should, but then the page gets rerendered and the h4 and h6 text appear but buttons do not appear and the "Loading..." appears instead. I'm not sure why and could use some help

Comment: Where is Car defined? Note that it doesn't really make sense for the h4 and h6 to render, but also "Loading...", since these are in completely separate paths based on a boolean condition. You can only have one or the other, not both (at the same time). You'll probably have to answer that for yourself as it seems unanswerable from this side.

Comment: And what is `CarBase` up to?  And why inject `IJSRuntime` if there's not more hidden code?  The first pass is the pre-render, the second is the interactive render.  `Car` is null in that context.  you need to debug to find out why.